# Add raw SQL to database query builder

Tags: laravel

I have the following SQL which provides me with the position of a particular record in the database given specific filters and ordering.

```php
\DB::select("SELECT
    t.id,
    t.position
  FROM (
    SELECT estimations.id,
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
    FROM estimations
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    WHERE estimations.is_archived = 1
    ORDER BY estimations.start desc, estimations.name) t
  WHERE t.id = " . $this->id);
```

For the inner query, I want to use the eloquent model `Estimation` so that I can use its query scopes. I want to use the model so that if the scope is updated down the line, this query will reflect the change...

```php
$innerQuery = Estimation::select('id')
    ->addSelect(\DB::raw('@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position'))
    // Need to add "JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r" 
    ->archived();
```

---

#### Attempt 1 - failed

Use the `join` method and pass in some generic arguments...

```php
$innerQuery = Estimation::select('id')
   ->addSelect(\DB::raw('@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position'))
   ->join('(SELECT @rownum := 0) r', '1', '=', '1')
   ->archived();
```

While the above gives me the correct SQL if I dump it, `$innerQuery->toSql()` it fails when I run it, `$innerQuery->get()` with the following error...

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_db.(select @rownum := 0) r' doesn't exist (SQL: SELECT temp.id, temp.position FROM (select `id`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position from `estimations` inner join `(SELECT @rownum := 0) r` on `1` = `1` where `is_archived` = ? order by `start` desc, `name` asc) temp WHERE temp.id = 4)

---

#### Attempt 2 - failed

As above but using `DB::raw()` for the `join()` (suggested by Jonas Staudenmeir),

```php
$innerQuery = Estimation::select('id')
   ->addSelect(\DB::raw('@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position'))
   ->join(\DB::raw('(SELECT @rownum := 0) r'), '1', '=', '1')
   ->archived();
```

Running `$innerQuery->get()` results in the following error...

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `id`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position from `estimations` inner join (SELECT @rownum := 0) r on `1` = `1` where `is_archived` = 1 order by `start` desc, `name` asc)

---

#### Attempt 3 - failed

As above, adding `DB::raw()` for all `join()` values (thanks again Jonas Staudenmeir),

```php
$innerQuery = Estimation::select('id')
   ->addSelect(\DB::raw('@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position'))
   ->join(\DB::raw('(SELECT @rownum := 0) r'), \DB::raw('1'), '=', \DB::raw('1'))
   ->archived();
```

This works on its own `$innerQuery->get();`, but when inserted into the outer query,

```php
$res = \DB::select('SELECT
    t.id,
    t.position
  FROM (' . $innerQuery->toSql() . ') t
  WHERE t.id = ' . $this->id);
```

I get the error...

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: SELECT t.id, t.position FROM (select `id`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position from `estimations` inner join (SELECT @rownum := 0) r on 1 = 1 where `is_archived` = ? order by `start` desc, `name` asc) t WHERE t.id = 3)

Is this because `scopeArchived()` filters by a value, which is shown as a `?` in the error? How can I avoid this?

Here's the code for `scopeArchived()`,

```php
public function scopeArchived($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_archived', true)->ordered('start', 'desc');
}
```

Removing `->where('is_archived', true)` results in no error, but obviously not the results I'm after.

---

#### Attempt 4 - solved

(Thanks Jonas Staudenmeir) - use `fromSub()` for the outer query. Here's the complete code...

```php
$innerQuery = Estimation::select('id')
    ->addSelect(\DB::raw('@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position'))
    ->join(\DB::raw('(SELECT @rownum := 0) r'), \DB::raw('1'), '=', \DB::raw('1'))
   ->archived();

$res = \DB::query()->fromSub($innerQuery, 'temp')
    ->select('id', 'position')
    ->where('id', $this->id)
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOIN "table" and "columns" can't be in backticks. You have to use raw expressions:

```php
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT @rownum := 0) r'), DB::raw('1'), '=', DB::raw('1'))
```

Comment: Thanks, have tried that but got a different error - see above. It seems that the query builder assumes a real table is being joined. Removing `, '1', '=', '1'` results in a "too few argumants" error.

Comment: You also have to use raw expressions for the "columns". I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have been so quick to accept - doesn't work when inserted into the outer query - see above.

Comment: That's a different issue. You can use `->where('is_archived', DB::raw('1'))`. Or better: [fromSub()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51599094/4848587)