# Laravel Nested Select + MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can i do a nested select using Laravel raw query?

```
SELECT day_of_week, AVG(order_count) average_order FROM 
(
  SELECT DAYNAME(order_date) day_of_week, 
         DAYOFWEEK(order_date) day_num, 
         TO_DAYS(order_date) date,
         count(*) order_count
  FROM orders 
  GROUP BY date
) temp
GROUP BY day_of_week 
ORDER BY day_num
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
DB::table('(
              SELECT DAYNAME(order_date) day_of_week, 
                     DAYOFWEEK(order_date) day_num, 
                     TO_DAYS(order_date) date,
                     count(*) order_count
              FROM orders 
              GROUP BY date
            ) temp')
            ->select(DB::raw('day_of_week, AVG(order_count) average_order'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('day_of_week'))
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('day_num'))
            ->get();
```

This is not working, but so far this query is very close.

By the way, I am using Laravel 5.6.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's your Laravel version?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir i've updated my question with the query that I tried.  I am using Laravel 5.6.

Comment: there is method in laravel of using raw query did you try that @PinoyStackOverflower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DB::raw()` in `table()` and don't use it in `groupBy()` and `orderBy()`:

```php
DB::table(DB::raw('(
      SELECT DAYNAME(order_date) day_of_week, 
             DAYOFWEEK(order_date) day_num, 
             TO_DAYS(order_date) date,
             count(*) order_count
      FROM orders 
      GROUP BY date
    ) temp'))
    ->select('day_of_week', DB::raw('AVG(order_count) average_order'))
    ->groupBy('day_of_week')
    ->orderBy('day_num')
    ->get();
```

You can also use `fromSub()`:

```php
$from = DB::table('orders')
    ->selectRaw(
        'DAYNAME(order_date) day_of_week,
        DAYOFWEEK(order_date) day_num, 
        TO_DAYS(order_date) date,
        count(*) order_count'
    )->groupBy('date');
DB::query()->fromSub($from, 'temp')
    ->select('day_of_week', DB::raw('AVG(order_count) average_order'))
    ->groupBy('day_of_week')
    ->orderBy('day_num')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I wasn't aware I can use DB::raw in the table. Thanks much for this! You are a savior!

Answer (score 0):

Try This , 
but surely it's need to edit

```
DB::table('orders')
    ->select(DB::raw('(SELECT order_date AS day_of_week, order_date AS day_num, order_date AS date FROM orders GROUP BY date)'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('day_of_week'))
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('day_num'))
    ->get();
```