# Convert SQL to eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

How can i convert this code `sql` into `eloquent`?

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(FLOOR(sum(diferenca)/60),'h',MOD(sum(diferenca),60),'m') as tempo
FROM
(SELECT
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m1.created_at, min(m2.created_at)) as diferenca
FROM
    mensagens m1
JOIN
    mensagens m2 ON m1.remetente_id = m2.destinatario_id AND m2.remetente_id = m1.destinatario_id AND m2.created_at > m1.created_at
GROUP BY
    m1.id) AS table1
WHERE
    (SELECT
        MIN(id)
    FROM
        mensagens
    WHERE
        destinatario_id = 2);
```

I trying like this, but no success. is giving me error because it is treating the concat select as a column.

```
Mensagem::whereIn('id', function($query) {
     $query->selectRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m1.created_at, min(m2.created_at)) as diferenca')
        ->from('mensagens as m1')
        ->join('mensagens as m2', 'm1.remetente_id', '=', 'm2.destinatario_id')
        ->where('m2.created_at', '>', 'm1.created_at')
        ->groupBy('m1.id');
     })
     ->where(function($query) {
           $query->selectRaw('min(id)')
                ->from('mensagens')
                ->where('destinatario_id', 2);
     })
    ->select("CONCAT(FLOOR(sum(diferenca)/60),'h',MOD(sum(diferenca),60),'m') as tempo")
      ->get();
```

Comment: Use `selectRaw()` instead of `select()`.

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek i need to get the average of responses in hours and minutes. If you know a better way to do this, i accept .

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir This solved the previous error, but now the second selectRaw does not detect the "diferenca" of the first selectRaw. "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'diferenca' in 'field list'".

Comment: You have to use `fromSub()` instead of `whereIn()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51599094/4848587